# Proving sets and subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i am having a little bit of trouble getting my head around this question.

if A, B and C are subsets of the universal set U then:
Prove that (B \ A) \ C = B \ (A ∪ C)

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Try to unwind the two formulas... $x \in (B \ A) \ C$ iff $[(x \in B \text { 
 and } x \notin A) \text { and } x \notin C]$ and the same for the RHS.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think you mean "Try to unwind the two formulas... x∈(B$\backslash$ A) $\backslash$ C iff [(x∈B and x∉A) and x∉C] and the same for the RHS."